# What is the Krull dimension of this local ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, krull-dimension

> I want to know what is the dimension of this ring $\mathbb C[x,y]_{(0,0)}/(y^2-x^7,y^5-x^3)$.

I don't know how to do that. If I suppose $y^2=x^7$ I will get a higher degree of $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We compute in the local ring:
$$y^{6}=(y^2)^3=(x^7)^3=(x^3)^7=(y^5)^7=y^{35}$$
Hence, $y^6(1-y^{29})=0$. Since $y$ belongs to the maximal ideal, it follows that $1-y^{29}$ is a unit, hence $y^6=0$. Similarly one obtains $x^6=0$. Hence, the local ring modulo nilpotents (this doesn't change dimension) is just $\mathbb{C}$, which is $0$-dimensional.

Comment: how's about the other local rings of each maximal ideals in $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-x^7,y^5-x^3)$ are their dimension the same,I don't know the difference

Comment: What does your geometric intuition tell you? This is an intersection of two curves.

Comment: actually I still don't know,when other cases $y^6$ is a unit and $y^{29-1}$ is a unit,but what's the local ring modulo nilpotents,and it's denmension and basis?